# Why in material-ui it is not accepted to have a table of 100% height?

Tags: material-ui

I've posted [an issue on the material-ui's github](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/4071) and I was instructed to post a question on SO, so here it goes.

I want to have a [table](http://www.material-ui.com/v0.15.0-alpha.2/#/components/table) which fills its parent's height (100%) while its header is fixed at the top and not scrolled away. Right now (v0.15.0-beta2) if you set a table's height to 100%, its header won't be fixed (even though you've set it to) and if you scroll, you are gonna loose the header. So I posted this behavior as an issue on the project's github. As my response I got:

> If you need a scroll you will always have to mention a height. like
>   height: 400px or some value.

Why is that? Personally I find it much more practical to have a "fill out" table than a "fixed one"! Specially since you can implement the second one with the first!